# How to configure vscode terminal command line prompt color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In ~/.bash_profile， I added this line:

```sh
PS1="[\[\e[33;m\]\t \[\e[32;m\]\u@\H \[\e[31;m\]\W]\[\e[33;m\]\#\e[m\$ "
```

And in iterm2, the command line prompt looks like below:

[image]

But when I launched vscode and opened the terminal, the terminal looks like this:

[image]

How can I configure the vscode terminal prompt to be colorful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problems are the `;`'s before the `m`'s.  Try this:

`PS1="[\[\e[33m\]\t \[\e[32m\]\u@\H \[\e[31m\]\W]\[\e[33m\]\#\[\e[m\$"`

Comment: You are right, the semicolon caused my problem . I finally edit it as: PS1="[\[\e[33m\]\t \[\e[32m\]\u@\H \[\e[31m\]\W]\[\e[33m\]\#\e[m$"  . Thanks a lot ~

Comment: I added the `\#` back in to my answer - I removed it while testing this.